# Can a Corda node expire from the network map?

Tags: corda

If I run a node for only an hour a day will the network map cache list this node when it is offline?

For example: if I only run a node fro 7-8am will the node be visible on the Network Map at 2pm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes are only removed from the Network Map if the node is offline beyond the event horizon length established for the network. As long as the node comes online before the event horizon timeout period runs out the node will remain listed in the Network map.

More information on the event horizon is listed here: https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#network-parameters

> eventHorizon: Time after which nodes are considered to be unresponsive and removed from network map. Nodes republish their NodeInfo on a regular interval. Network map treats that as a heartbeat from the node.